# Mysql extract json data and search multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, json, string, where-clause

Hi I have car listing website and I want to filter multiple values from a JSON column `data`

My database table looks like this:

```
id | label    | data
---|----------|---------------------------------
 1 | "test 1" | {"Year":"2014","Gear":"Auto"}
 2 | "test 2" | {"Year":"2010","Gear":"Manual"}
 3 | "test 3" | {"Year":"2009","Gear":"None"}
```

For example I want to filter by Gear, either "Auto" or "Manual":

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE 
JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.Year") in (2010,2014) AND
JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.Gear") in ("Auto","Manual")
```

The query returns zero results when I add the filter for `Gear`, but the filter for `Year` works fine.

Comment: I dont see a question or a description of a problem here!

Comment: JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.Gear") in ("Automatic","Manuel") this code not working

Comment: You need to describe your goal in detail before we can help you figure out where you're going wrong.

Comment: Of course sorry my english, i have json data from mysql column, when i select checkbox "Automatic" and "Manual" i want listing all this records

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`JSON_EXTRACT` returns a JSON string](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract), which includes quotation marks. You can either include this in your search:

```sql
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.Year") in (2010,2014)
    AND JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.Gear') IN ('"Manual"','"Auto"');
```

Or use [the `JSON_UNQUOTE` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote):

```sql
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(data, "$.Year") in (2010,2014)
    AND JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.Gear')) IN ('Manual','Auto');
```

See fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fC48mHEM1nuLUZCTP8CLfs/0

Comment: Thank you!! I'm really happy right now, its working! really thank you again!

Comment: Happy to help, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: This not work from array json ["2010","2014", ...] :(

Comment: @JorhelReyes get the same issue, you found something else?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend [json operator `->>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-inline-path), which combines `JSON_EXTRACT()` and `JSON_UNQUOTE()`:

```
select * 
from test
where data ->> '$.Year' in (2010, 2014) and data ->> '$.Gear' in ('Manual', 'Auto');
```

`->>` was added in MySQL 5.7.13.

Comment: Nice one, I knew about the `->` operator but not `->>`

Comment: Warning: this method with operators "->" and "->>" not work in MariaDB 10.7. It's only work with MySQL at this moment.